# How to secure SSH key file in AWX Tower?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I have to protect the key file of the server. Path of the key file is present in AWX Inventory file, as you can see below. I used ansible-vault to protect the "/var/lib/awx/resource/keys/stg01/test.pem" file. How can i load that password in my AWX inventory file. How to encrypt the key file and pass that file to ansible tower,it needs to decrypted when using that key file.

```
---
 ansible_ssh_host: 10.3.2.10
 ansible_ssh_private_key_file: /var/lib/awx/resource/keys/stg01/test.pem
 ansible_user: centos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ansible-vault, you need to have a file with the master password of ansible-vault or to set the password in command line everytime you use it.

If you don't want to have that to do, you can look vault server and use it with ansible:

https://www.vaultproject.io/